# how to display the product of checkbox and dropdown list in number box

Tags: javascript, html

here is my catalogue codes. want to display the value of the checkbox multiplied to the value of the dropdown list and output the product to the . just html and javascript codes are to be used.

```
<table align=center border=1>
<tr colspan=3>
<td colspan=3><h2>Specialty Cakes</h2></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src=special\blackforest_small.jpg valign=center-right><br><center>Black Forest</td>
<td>Chocolate sponge layered with sugar syrup and Kirsch flavouring, white mousse and dark sweet cherries.</td>
<td><input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="550.00"onclick="product1()">Buy P550.00</input><br><input type="number" id="total1" name="total1" value="P0.00"size="8"></input><br>
QTY: <select id="qty1" name="qty1" onchange="product1()">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
<script>
var m = document.getElementById("check1").checked;
function product1(){
var x = document.getElementById("check1").value;
var y = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
var z = 0;
if (m = true){
z = "P" + x * y;
}
document.getElementById("total1").value = z;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your input with id total1 as a type = number - but you are assigning it a text value of P0.00   change its type to text and it will work, or give it a numeric value.

Comment: it works...thanks for the advice @Symeon. haven't notice that one.

Comment: can I also ask for advice on how to bring back the total1 to "P0.00" value if I uncheck the checkbox? also even if it is unchecked if I change the qty1 the total1 still calculate the product

Comment: thee where several things wrong in your script - i have done a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/5gfkLd8v/  to show it working